# how can I extract repo A's GITHUB_TOKEN in repo B?

Tags: github-actions, github-api, github-token

Is there a way to extract `GITHUB_TOKEN` belongs to one repo to another repo in the same organization?

I am working on fetching the GitHub limit rate data for repo A by calling the GitHub API. But I cannot simply implement the workflow in that repo A since the workflow needs to be triggered too frequently. I have to put the workflow in repo B, and call the GitHub api by using the `GITHUB_TOKEN` of repo A. However, I do not know how to use the repo A's `GITHUB_TOKEN` in repo B. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to call the `GITHUB_TOKEN` in repo B, but it has the different usage with the repo A. Does anyone have experience about it?

Thx so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe github actions secrets sounds like the best fit, you should get the token from repo A and add it as a secret REPO_A_KEY in repo B's [https://github.com/{youracc}/{repoBname}/settings/secrets/actions](https://github.com/%7Byouracc%7D/%7BrepoBname%7D/settings/secrets/actions).

Then in a github action you access the variable like ${{secrets.REPO_A_KEY}}